# widget looses onClickPendingIntent on Samsung Galaxy S3

Tags: android, widget, samsung-mobile

I use the normal routine to make a view on the widget clickable:

```
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, OnOff_screen.class);
        intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, widgetId); // Identifies the particular widget...
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        // Make the pending intent unique...
        Uri data = Uri.withAppendedPath(
            Uri.parse(Intent.URI_INTENT_SCHEME + "://widget/id/"),
            String.valueOf(widgetId));
        intent.setData(data);

        PendingIntent pendIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
            intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        //start the activity when clicking on the view
        views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.tc_logo, pendIntent);
```

While this works on ALL mobile phones, only on Samsung Galaxy S3 the widget does not react to any clicks after about 20 min or so.

Right after the widget is installed everything is OK on the S3.

But just waiting for about 20 minutesor so the click on the view does not fire anymore - as if the view just looses the setOnClickPendingIntent.

Once the widget is installed again, everything works again - but looses the clickabilty again after about 20min.

This is only on Samsung Galaxy S3 - all other devices are OK.

ps I also found that some other widgets like the clock from Samsung itself just stopps and does not update anymore.

What is so SPECIAL on the S3 that destroys the widget functionality?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

...finally we found the reason for this problem to be a fault in Samsung's Android implementation of the used version. Thanks to Samsung amazing support we could confirm this issue and Samsung promised to resolve this in the next updates!